# Hausdorff expansion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

Could someone explain me, what the Hausdorff expansion is?
In my quantum mechanics homework I should use something called the Hausdorff expansion which looks like the following:
$$e^ABe^{-A}=B+[A,B]+\frac{1}{2!}[A,[A,B]]+\frac{1}{3!}[A,[A,[A,B]]]+...$$
and I don't really understand what it is or why is it good.

Comment: What part of it do you not "really understand"?

Comment: No, what you just wrote down is a simple combinatoric [Lemma of Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma) useful in working out the CBH expansion. If that's all you want, WP proves it just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When A and B do not commute with each other, one can not write $e^A B e^{-A} = e^A e^{-A} B = B$. What you can do is to expand the exponentials and calculate term by term. When you expand them here, you get
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
e^A B e^{-A} & = (1 + A + \frac{A^2}{2!} + \cdots) B (1 - A + \frac{A^2}{2!} - \cdots) \\
 & = (B + AB + \frac{A^2 B}{2!} + \cdots)(1 - A + \frac{A^2}{2!} - \cdots) \\
 & = B + AB + \frac{A^2 B}{2!} - BA - ABA + \frac{B A^2}{2!} + higher~orders \\
 & = B + [A, B] + \frac{1}{2!}(A^2 B - 2 ABA + BA^2) + \cdots\\
 & = B + [A, B] + \frac{1}{2!} [A, [A, B]] + \cdots\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

There you arrive at the formula for the Hadamard expansion.